# Binding a property inside observerList in wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I am writing an application in C#, WPF, XAML using MVVM patterm.

After many examples that I founded online the data that I try to Bind to the UI is not shown in the screen.

My architecture is : In the MainViewModel I have an ObserverList from type family,
in Family class I have an ObserverList from type Child,
in Child class I have Name.

How to Bind the Child Name in to TextBlock?

Some examples that I founded:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970558%28v=vs.110%29.aspxv

```
<Window x:Class="DataTemplates.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataTemplates"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="350"
        Width="525">
  <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate"
                  DataType="local:MyData">
      <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                   Text="First Name: " />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                   Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2"
                   Text="Last Name: " />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3"
                   Text="{Binding Path=LastName}" />
        <CheckBox Grid.Column="4"
                  Content="Is Lecturer?"
                  IsEnabled="False"
                  IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsLecturer}" />
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>
  <StackPanel>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}"
             ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyDataTemplate}"
             HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" />
    <Button Content="Add"
            Click="Button_Click" />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

and the code Behind

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace CollectionDemo
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
  /// </summary>
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    private ObservableCollection<MyData> _myCollection =
      new ObservableCollection<MyData>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();

      DataContext = _myCollection;
      _myCollection.Add(
        new MyData
        {
          FirstName = "Arik",
          LastName = "Poznanski",
          IsLecturer = true
        });
      _myCollection.Add(
        new MyData
        {
          FirstName = "John",
          LastName = "Smith",
          IsLecturer = false
        });
    }

    private int counter = 0;
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      ++counter;
      _myCollection.Add(
          new MyData()
          {
            FirstName = "item " + counter,
            LastName = "item " + counter,
            IsLecturer = counter % 3 == 0
          });
    }
  }
}
```

class my data form the example

```
public class MyData
  {
    public string User { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
  }
```

Comment: Hello can you add the `MyData` class?

Comment: I add it below the code behind

Comment: `new MyData
        {
          FirstName = "John",
          LastName = "Smith",
          IsLecturer = false
        }` yet `public class MyData
  {
    public string User { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
  }` I think not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a custom example which matches your scenario, take a look at this.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="SO.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
        <TextBlock Height="30" Text="{Binding Parent.Child.SampleText}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MainViewModel obj = new MainViewModel();
            this.DataContext = obj; 
        }
}
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
public class MainViewModel
    {
        private ParentModel _Parent = new ParentModel();

        public ParentModel Parent
        {
            get { return _Parent; }
            set { _Parent = value; }
        }

        public MainViewModel() //Data Load in Constructor
        {
            ChildModel child = new ChildModel();
            child.SampleText = "Hi, I am Child!";
            Parent.Child = child;
        }
    }
```

**ParentModel.cs**

```
public class ParentModel
    {
        private ChildModel _Child = new ChildModel();

        public ChildModel Child
        {
            get { return _Child; }
            set { _Child = value; }
        }

    }
```

**ChildModel.cs**

```
public class ChildModel
    {
        private string _SampleText ;

        public string SampleText
        {
            get { return _SampleText; }
            set { _SampleText = value; }
        }

    }
```

**Corrections in your eg:**
Your View and Code behind is perfect.

You didn't add properties in model class which is to be binded in UI.

```
class MyData
    {
        //public string User { get; set; }
        //public string Password { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public bool IsLecturer { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering and commented but unfortunately you didn't answered the question. You referenced to the example.

Comment: Please take a look at the newly added example in my answer . It will help in your case.

Comment: Ok. Thanks, ufter I fixed it I still have the binding problem.. how ti bind an element that in observerList in an Observer list as you can see in the first part in the post

Comment: But how the xaml code will look if in the ParentModal the property is ObserverList<ChildModel> Children {get;set;}?